# Bind a property to another property in C#

Tags: c#, data-binding, properties, delegates, inotifypropertychanged

I have a Class called `Grid` that is composed of two other classes: `Circle` and `Line`. Here is the code for these classes:

```
public class Grid
{
    public Circle Circle {get; set;}
    public Line Line {get; set;}
}
```

I want the geometry of `Line` to stay connected to the geometry of the `Circle`. This means that when I move the `Circle`, I want the `Line` to be notified and update its geometry to match the new location of the `Circle`. I could create a new `Grid` with the updated geometries of the `Circle` and Line, but I don't want to create a new `Grid`. Instead, I want to bind the endpoints of the `Line` to the `Circle`, for example to its center.

What technologies in C# can I use to achieve this? Are delegates or the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface suitable for this purpose?

Comment: The fact that you've tagged your question with `inotifypropertychanged` implies that you already know the answer to your question. Read the mouseover text that you get when hovering over the tag.

Comment: @Flater I'm not really sure to be honest. I do not know how to implement it in this case.

Comment: Well, try implementing it and come back to us if you run into any issues. StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. [Here's an official MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface). You can also use google to find step by step tutorials.

Comment: @Flater You are misleading my original question. The question is not about how to implement it via inotifypropertychanged. It is about what technologies exist in C# to achieve this the right way.

Comment: _"It is about what technologies exist in C# to achieve this the right way"_ The answer is **INotifyPropertyChanged**. How is this not answered by reading the mouseover text of the tag? _"INotifyPropertyChanged is an interface defined in Microsoft .NET used to notify listeners of data changes made to an object. These notifications enable data-bound UI controls to update their display automatically whenever the data properties they are bound to have changed."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Circle : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int radius;       
    public int Radius 
    {
        get { return radius; }
        set 
        {
            radius = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Radius");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propChange = PropertyChanged;
        if (propChange == null) return;
        propChange(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then in Grid.cs

```
public class Grid
{
    private Circle circle;
    public Circle Circle 
    {
       get { return circle; }
       set 
       {
           circle = value;
           if (circle != null) 
              circle.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
       }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Radius")
            // Do something to Line
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this only works if you set `Circle` (or `Line`) to a **new instance** of a Circle (or Line). Not if the existing Circle (or Line)'s properties are changed.